# Typo3 10.4.x Upgrade

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

Im on Typo3 10.4.9 and want to upgrade to 10.4.16. Tried this in the backend Upgrade - Typo3 Core. This is the output:

```
System can be updated
Skipped download of TYPO3 CMS core. A core source directory already exists in destination path. Using this instead.
Verifying existing TYPO3 CMS core checksum is not possible
Unpacking TYPO3 CMS core files skipped
Moving TYPO3 CMS core files skipped
Core updated - please reload your browser
```

... but the update didnt work, im still on 10.4.9. Andy idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: Download 10.4.16 sources, unpack and change symlink `typo3_src` to the newer version. After that go to the backend and perform all required operations (if any)

Answer (score 1):

Could you show us or verify your folder structure?

According to the [Installation and Upgrade Guide](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/QuickInstall/GetAndUnpack/Index.html#installing-on-a-unix-server),

> You end up with the following structure of files:

```
typo3_src-10.4.x/
public/typo3_src -> ../typo3_src-10.4.x/
public/typo3 -> typo3_src/typo3/
public/index.php -> typo3_src/index.php
```

> This setup allows the administrator to use the “Core Updater” feature
> in the Admin Tool / Maintenance area to update the TYPO3 installation.